# A SQL function with a pure select result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

At first I should say I am newbie in SQL functions or store procedures, I want to know how can I create a sql function or store procedures with some filters and sorting but at least it return just a pure select without showing filters and sorts

I mean I want to create something like this function :

```
function {
SELECT * FROM Customers
Where (ID = @p1)
ORDER BY @P2 DESC;
}
```

but it returns just this select commend to me :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
```

but what it returns filtered and sorted.

how can I do this? I should do this with functions or store procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Stored Procedure or a table-valued function:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc @P1 int, @P2 int as
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, LastOrderNum, LastPurchaseDate
    FROM Customers
    WHERE ID = @P1
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN @P2 = 0 THEN LastName ELSE LastPurchaseDate END DESC;
END
```

> usage: `exec MyProc 10, 1;`

Or:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_schema.MyTableFun (@P1 int, @P2 int) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT FirstName, LastName, LastOrderNum, LastPurchaseDate
    FROM Customers
    WHERE ID = @P1
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN @P2 = 0 THEN LastName ELSE LastPurchaseDate END DESC;
```

> usage:
>       `SELECT * FROM my_schema.MyTableFun(10, 1);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. let me test it